# How do you get p-values for predictors in a Cox regression analysis in R?

Tags: r, interpretation, cox-model

I am running a Cox regression analysis in R where both my predictors are binary (`Animal_Number`: *single* vs. *paired*; and `Treatment`: *control* vs. *exposed*). I therefore have four groups (*single control*, *paired control*, *single exposed* and *paired exposed*). When I run my Cox regression, I get the following output (excerpt):

```
                                        coef exp(coef) se(coef)      z Pr(>|z|)   
Animal_NumberPaired                   0.2617    1.2991   0.3303  0.792  0.42829   
TreatmentExposed                     -1.4031    0.2458   0.4715 -2.976  0.00292 **
Animal_NumberPaired:TreatmentExposed  1.0246    2.7861   0.5817  1.762  0.07814 .
```

As I understand it, the three lines presented here are simply the levels of the factors being compared to the baseline experimental group, which was set as *single control*, i.e., the first line is comparing single control animals with paired control animals.

If this is the case, how then does one find information (`coefs`, `z`, `p-value`, etc.) for purely the effect of `Animal_Number`, `Treatment` and their interaction? I can seem to do this in SPSS, and get the following:

```
                           B    SE      Wald    df  Sig.   Exp(B)
Animal_Number             .244  .331    .545    1   .461   1.276
Treatment               -1.283  .472    7.399   1   .007    .277
Animal_Number*Treatment   .959  .582    2.717   1   .099   2.609
```

But I want to be able to do it in R. I considered using likelihood ratio tests, to compare full and reduced models, but then information about the coefficients and z is lost.

Comment: When you have categorical independent variables, you are always comparing levels, but there is a variety of contrasts, defining what you are comparing to what. I don't know what SPSS defaults to, nor what you mean by "pure".

Answer (score 3):

@Peter Flom is right.  You are always comparing levels with categorical IVs.  SPSS is simply presenting your results in a way that obscures that fact from you.

In this specific case, since each of your IV's has only two levels, the reported p-values are the ones you want.  (Note that if you had >2 levels, you would want to use `anova()` to get the appropriate p-value for the factor.)

An additional issue here is that you have an interaction term included in your model.  The rule is that when you have an interaction you don't interpret the main effects.  In your case the interaction term is not 'significant' by conventional standards, but it is close enough that I wouldn't want to interpret the main effects anyway.  What this means then is that the results for, say, `Animal_Number` only pertain to the case where `Treatment` is *control*.  Basically, when there is an interaction, there is no such thing as 'the *pure* effect of a variable'.

I also notice that the results from R and SPSS differ.  That is unsettling, but based on what's provided, I can't tell why this happened.

Comment: I understand that we're always comparing levels within categorical independent variables, but the way I was told to understand this output is that, for example, because the baseline is set as single control, for Animal_Number, the baseline is being compared to paired control- is that correct? Therefore, if I were to write a statement like 'there was no impact of animal number on survival (p<0.05)', this wouldn't be correct, as the first line of the output is actually representing the comparison of single control vs. paired control? Or am I interpreting this incorrectly?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue too:

Here is the reason.
The contrast method in play is `treatment.contrast()`.

For categorical variables this method creates a dummy for each category

So for `animal_number` there are two possible dummies

`Animal_number single` - a dummy variable which is 0 if a case is not single and 1 for single cases

`Animal _number paired` - a dummy which is 0 for paired cases and 1 for single cases

The same happens for Treatment groups where

`Treatment control`  is a dummy equal to 1 for control group cases and 0 for exposed group

`Treatment exposed` - a dummy equal to  0 for control group and 1 for exposed group

For each factor the dummies are perfectly correlated so you must exclude either the intercept or one dummy for each factor.The default is to exclude the dummy for the first level.

Which is single for animal number and  control for Treatment.

```
|----------------|----------------------|-------------------|------------|
|      Group.    | Animal_number paired.| Treatment exposed.| Interaction|
|----------------|----------------------|-------------------|------------|
|Single control. |    0.                |    0.             |         0  |
|----------------|----------------------|-------------------|------------|
|Single exposed. |    0.                |    1.             |         0  |
|----------------|----------------------|-------------------|------------|
|Paired control. |    1.                |    0.             |         0  |
|----------------|----------------------|-------------------|------------|
|Paired exposed. |    1.                |    1.             |         1  |
|----------------|----------------------|-------------------|------------|
```

So as you can see the interaction has only 2 outcomes
0/1

The coefficient for the interaction is the average difference  in log hazard ratio for the category =1 compared to the other 3 groups.

for my case i decided to omit the main effects leaving the simple effects
this way;

`coxph(Surv(time,status)~Animal_Number*Treatment- Animal_Number-Treatment,data=data)`